# What would be the variable type for my Typescript variable?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that looks like:

```
interface IMenu {
  name: string;
  page: any;
  quantity: number;
  headerColor: string;
  icon: string;
  unitsList: IUnitInfo[];
  pageType: UnitPageType;
}
```

The variable that I want to assign a type has that kind of value assigned to it:

```
this._menus = [
    {    
        name: 'menu1',
        page: page1,
        quantity: 2,
        headerColor: "red",
        icon: "arrow",
        unitsList: this._unitsList,
        pageType: UnitPageType.All
    },
    {
        name: 'menu2',
        page: page2,
        quantity: 4,
        headerColor: "orange",
        icon: "phone",
        unitsList: 0,
        pageType: UnitPageType.None
    }
];
```

Right now, if I do this, it gives me a warning:

```
private _menus: IMenu[];
```

So, what would be the right type?

Thanks

Comment: "it gives me a warning" -- what warning? Looks like `unitsList: 0` is wrong, since `0` is a number, but `unitsList` is type `IUnitInfo[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work as long as every element you add to the array is compatible with the `IMenu` interface:

```
var menus: IMenu[] = [
    {    
        name: 'menu1',
        page: page1,
        quantity: 2,
        headerColor: "red",
        icon: "arrow",
        unitsList: this._unitsList,
        pageType: UnitPageType.All
    },
    {
        name: 'menu2',
        page: page2,
        quantity: 4,
        headerColor: "orange",
        icon: "phone",
        unitsList: [],
        pageType: UnitPageType.None
    }
];
```

In fact, this is why it is a good idea to type your `_menus` member, because it is already catching a possibly unintentional error in your code (your use of `0` where an array of `IUnitInfo` is expected.

If this isn't an error, you can make your interface aware that this is acceptable, using a union type like this:

```
unitsList: number | any[];
```

Either of these will fix the issue - so you can decide which is valid in your case.